# crash while trying push view controllers with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, quartz-core

I have code to store references to 3 Viewcontrollers (say of class typeA) on UINavigation controller stack, and later all these view controllers are popped out of stack.

Later upon button click, I try to push 2 viewcontrollers normally and then for 3rd view controller I'm using following method.

```
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```

Navigation happens this way 
`classTypeA VC1-- > classTypeA VC2 --> classTypeA VC3 --> "class TypeB VC" --> classTypeA VC1-- > classTypeA VC2 --> classTypeA VC3 --> "class TypeB VC" --> classTypeA VC1-- > classTypeA VC2 --> classTypeA VC3 --> "class TypeB VC"`  (it cashes at this point).

This code works well when user navigates slowly, but if user clicks button faster this crashes with exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view
>   controller instance more than once is not supported'.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: add your language tag is objective C or swift

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are putting two instances of a `viewcontroller` in `yourNavigationViewController` so before pushing on `viewcontroller` you should remove instance if present like this -

```
func RemoveViewControllersFromNavigationController(vcClass:AnyClass)->Void
{

        let array = self.navigationController?.viewControllers


        if array != nil
        {
            for aviewcontroller  in array!
            {
                if aviewcontroller.isKindOfClass(vcClass)
                {
                   self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAtIndex( (self.navigationController?.viewControllers.indexOf(aviewcontroller))!)
                }
            }

        }

}
```

call above method before pushing your `viewcontroller`

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc  = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventDetailViewController") as! EventDetailViewController
                   RemoveViewControllersFromNavigationController(EventDetailViewController)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: please look into question , I'm trying to push 3 view controllers of same classtype...your code can be used only when you are pushing only one Viewcontroller  , what if u wanted to push 3 Viewcontrollers which are of same class types but different instances?